# ActivityNotFoundException for class extends BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

My end objective is to learn data flow in contactless card transactions from beginning to end for the reason I am making an android application which will accept contactless cards. 
In the first screen I have a text box for entering amount and a button to accept it, which will take it to the next screen.
In the next screen I have a button which displays the amount and a button(Tap) which
 should start the broadcast listener( for testing sake I am trying to capture broadcast for AIRPLANE_MODE).
Now my issue is that whenever I press the Tap button, application says - unfortunately app has stopped.
In the debug I can see -

> Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find
>   explicit activity class
>   {com.example.myfirstapp/com.example.myfirstapp.AskToTapCard}; have you
>   declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml? .

But the class AskToTapCard extends from BroadcardListener. What I am expecting at this point is the application to wait and I will switch to airlane mode and app to detect it and log.
I made changes to make it extent from AppCompatActivity and show a dummy page, it shows. How to fix this ? In is a complete in house project and I can provide any source file, just let me know which one I need to. Below image may help you access the size of my project.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Instead of blunt down voting, can someone explain why. This is infact my first android development.

Comment: The error is self explanatory ... add the `BroadcastReceiver` to your app manifest. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html

Comment: @MarkKeen it is already. I have added my manifest file now. Please can you check whether it needs any modification.

Comment: See below from Budius

Comment: took a while to upload. now it is as a part of original question.

Comment: Yes. saw that. checking on how else to call the the receiver function from onclick function. I am a two day old android programmer :). Will need some time to.

Comment: pro tip about StackOverflow: DO NOT post screenshots of your code. Post just the actual text of the code. And see here how to format it nicely http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: If you are a 2-day-old Android programmer, perhaps you should follow some howto's or tutorials first to get the hang of it. There are lots of sample apps on developer.android.com and other websites. We aren't really here to teach you the basics, we are here to help with the more difficult stuff ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says: `ActivityNotFoundException` but `AskToTapCard` is not an `Activity`, it's a `BroadcastReceiver`.

So even thou you didn't show your code (and you should, it's one possible reason ppl is downvoting you), I can only assume you have something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AskToTapCard.class);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Which is exactly what the error is telling you. That you're telling the system to run an activity, but you give to the system a BroadcastReceiver. Once understanding the error the solution is simple:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AskToTapCard.class);
context.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: Probably, but i had mentioned I am ready to show any source, since I was not sure know which would actually help. People are so eager to downvote :)
Tap button onClick calls function getcardtap and I have used this. -     
public void getcardtap(View view)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AskToTapCard.class);

This should not be used in this case you mean ?

Comment: your comment makes me believe you did not properly read my answer. Please read all of it, note the different details on the first code and the second code I posted.

Comment: ok I am going to look at it carefully. I have been using like your first code snippet.

Comment: I have a made a receiver which is supposed to receive broadcast from system. and then I am trying to start it like an activity, which i should not be doing. Is this understanding correct ?

Comment: Exactly. `Activity`, `Service` and `Receiver` are separate components used for different reasons that are started in their own ways.

Comment: Now I have stopped calling my receiver as an activity and the current issue is fixed. Then the next issue I faced is my broadcast is active all the time. So now I use registereceiver in the activity where I want the broadcast to be active and unregisterReceiver in onPause and onStop. I have been testing with AIRPLANE mode.Now I can start on xpreia tags and contactless smart card. Thanks.